# authentication fail in web connector for connecting quickbooks

Tags: quickbooks

i am using localhost but please assume domainname.com is a localhost

QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : updateWS() for application = 'My QuickBooks SOAP Server' has STARTED
20140805.11:34:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.getUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock = FALSE
20140805.11:34:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to True
20140805.11:34:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session locked *********************
20140805.11:34:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : Initiated connection to the following application.
20140805.11:34:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppName: My QuickBooks SOAP Server
20140805.11:34:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppUniqueName (if available): My QuickBooks SOAP Server
20140805.11:34:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppURL: http://domainname.com/magece17/quickbooks-php-master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector.php
20140805.11:34:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : *** Calling serverVersion().
20140805.11:34:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : Actual error received from web service for serverVersion call: . For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-serverVersion.
20140805.11:34:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : This application does not contain support for serverVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20140805.11:34:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() :**  Calling clientVersion() with following parameter:
20140805.11:34:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.updateWS() : Actual error received from web service for clientVersion call: . For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-clientVersion.
20140805.11:34:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : This application does not contain support for clientVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20140805.11:34:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Authenticating to application 'My QuickBooks SOAP Server', username = 'quickbooks'
20140805.11:34:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() :  **Calling authenticate() with following parameters:
20140805.11:34:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message.
The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine
More info:
StackTrace =    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at QBWebConnector.domainname.com.WCWebServiceDoc.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.domainname.com.WCWebService.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.authenticate(String UserName, String Password)
   at QBWebConnector.WebService.do_authenticate(String& ticket, String& companyFileName)
Source = System.Web.Services
20140805.11:34:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
20140805.11:34:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20140805.11:34:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : Update completed with errors. See log (QWClog.txt) for details.

Answer (score 0):

This:

> QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message. The server committed a protocol violation.

Indicates a problem *with your web server*.

If you search online, the most commonly recommended solution is to add this to your config:

```
<system.net>
    <settings>
        <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />
    </settings>
</system.net>
```

*But*, with that said, you should check your web server error logs to see why it's throwing that error.

Comment: the webservice placed in linuxmint xampp local server.where i can place your code i mean which file i want use